# Uniqueness of Standard Model of Arithmetic

Tags: logic, arithmetic, model-theory

Is the standard model of arithmetic unique? If so, is there a proof of such or is it just a consequence of the definitions?

---

I was reading the following blog which references a standard model of Peano arithmetic: "These are often called ‘nonstandard’ models. If you take a model of Peano arithmetic—say, your favorite ‘standard’ model —" [link](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2018/03/03/nonstandard-integers-as-complex-numbers/). My question is how do we know that such is the only one?

Comment: Isn't a non-standard model of arithmetic *any model not isomorphic to the standard model*? What do you mean with **unique**?

Comment: The standard model is simply defined as a certain structure and is, as such, unique.  But I think your question is: is there a unique model for the typical axioms of arithmetic (= Peano Axioms)? To that, the answer is no.

Comment: I was reading the following blog which references a standard model of Peano arithmetic: "These are often called ‘nonstandard’ models. If you take a model of Peano arithmetic—say, your favorite ‘standard’ model —"                    [link] (https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2018/03/03/nonstandard-integers-as-complex-numbers/). My question is how do we know that such is the only one?

Comment: I disagree with the downvote. If one sees the phrase "the standard model" before being familiar with set theory, it's quite reasonable to worry that there's some question-begging here; and I think that this is a reasonably common occurrence based on some experiences I've had on this site. I think this is a fine question, and (per my answer) can in fact be meaningfully framed and addressed.

Comment: (That said, this question could certainly use a bit more context - I've edited in the OP's comment, which in my opinion improves the situation.)

Comment: What is a proof if not a consequence of the definitions?

Comment: @AsafKaragila you are correct, I should have said an obvious consequence not relying on other complicated machinery

Comment: The following 4 wikipedia links are of interest here: 
$\;$[Second order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic), $\;$[First order theory of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic)
$\;$[Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory: Axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#7._Axiom_of_infinity) and
[Non-standard model of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3230638/plurality-of-arithmetics-or-absoluteness-of-arithmetical-truths-i-e-are-all/3230706#3230706

Answer (score 8):

The standard model of arithmetic is indeed unique (up to isomorphism). Of course, to assert this we need to give the phrase above a precise definition ...

Say that a model $M$ of arithmetic is **standard** if for every other model $N$ of arithmetic there is a unique initial segment embedding *(= injective homomorphism with image an initial segment)* of $M$ into $N$. *There are in fact other definitions we could use here.*  We can prove that $(i)$ a standard model of arithmetic exists and $(ii)$ any two standard models of arithmetic are isomorphic *(indeed, uniquely isomorphic - if $M,N$ are standard models of arithmetic, then there is a unique isomorphism from $M$ to $N$)*. The latter justifies the use of "the" in "the standard model."

Of course, in stating the above we need to precisely define "arithmetic." But pretty much anything reasonable will work; in particular, the claim above is true for Robinson's Q and *(restricting attention to addition alone)* Presburger arithmetic.

The best intuition for this in my opinion is by **comparison**. Suppose $M,N$ are models of arithmetic; we can try to define an embedding of $M$ into $N$ in "stages" *(send the least element of $M$ to the least element of $N$, the next-least element of $M$ to the next-least element of $N$, ...)*. This will work for a while, but possibly not "all the way up" (maybe $M$ does not in fact embed into $N$). However, we can look at the subset of $M$ consisting of all $x$ such that *for every model $N$, the attempted-embedding-process works up to $x$.* The set of all such $x$ can then be shown to be a standard model of arithmetic.

- A bit more precisely: for a model $M$ of arithmetic, let $M_0$ be the set of $x\in M$ such that for every model $N$ of arithmetic there is some $y\in N$ such that $[0,x]^M$ is uniquely isomorphic to $[0,y]^N$, where "$[0,a]^B$" for $B$ a model of arithmetic and $a\in B$ is the "substructure"of $B$ consisting of all elements $\le a$ (it's not a *literal* substructure unless $a=0$, since if $a\not=0$ it's not closed under $+$ and $\times$, but we can resolve this either by talking about partial structures or by replacing $+$ and $\times$ with their corresponding "graph relations). It's not hard then to show that $M_0$ is a standard model of arithmetic.

---

Of course this depends on a **background theory** within which this proof takes place (this is distinct from the theory we choose to call "arithmetic" - we're proving something *about* arithmetic, *in the context of* a different, "larger" theory). Usually when we don't state that theory it's taken to be [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), and that certainly suffices here. However, in general ZFC is massive overkill, and this is such a case: the existence of the standard model of arithmetic can be appropriately stated and proved in the much weaker theory ACA$_0$, and in fact this is optimal in a precise sense (I don't know a citation for this fact but this is not hard to prove).

- Incidentally, the general study of what axioms are needed to prove particular theorems is indeed a topic of much interest, most of it falling under the umbrella of [**reverse mathematics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics)
- Also, it's worth pointing out that both ACA$_0$ and ZFC have a "distinguished" model of arithmetic, and so in each context we generally prove the stronger fact that *that distinguished model* is standard; indeed, in the ACA$_0$ context I think that's how we *have* to proceed.

On the other hand, we could always consider frameworks which **actively refute** *(rather than simply are too weak to prove)* the theorem above. See e.g. [this article of Yessenin-Volpin](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X08707389) (an ultrafinitist who interestingly believed that ZFC, and indeed much more, is *consistent*!) or more recently some approaches to [a multiverse framework of set theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.4223.pdf) *(see the discussion before the "well-foundedness mirage" bit on page $25$ - this would be an extreme version of that principle)*. Whether one finds these alternate theories compelling is of course subjective; personally, I happen to be at least somewhat sympathetic to them.

Comment: Incidentally it's worth pointing out that ACA$_0$ is drastically less well-known than ZFC; indeed, I'd be extremely surprised to find more than a few people outside logic who are familiar with it! This is because its primary interest is within logic. Outside logic the general interest in something like ZFC is instrumental: that it's an apparently-consistent theory within which basically all of math can be developed. So there's generally not much call for something like the (reverse-math-motivated) ACA$_0$ outside of logic. I mention it here, though, since I do think it's relevant to the issue.

Comment: Noah, to be fair, your answers are great. But do you ever spend a few minutes checking if something is a duplicate?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The closest thing I found was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257984/are-the-standard-natural-numbers-an-outstanding-model-of-pa), which I don't really think is an exact duplicate (although it's really close) since it's taking as *given* the existence of a thing we're considering the "standard model." Is there a closer duplicate I'm missing?

Comment: (To be fair I do take a somewhat restrictive view towards what constitutes an "exact duplicate," and I often do forget to check for duplicates. So you're not wrong.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Regarding your point about reverse mathematics, is there a particular axiom (or combination of axioms) of ACA0 that makes the standard model minimal model?

Comment: @AliquidExNihilo Well, ACA$_0$ is RCA$_0$ (which we consider to correspond to "computable" mathematics) together with a single new axiom; there are various ways to formulate this axiom, the most natural of which is probably "Every function has a range." To see why this is a nontrivial principle note that the range of a simple function can be quite complicated since a priori being certain that a given number is *not* in the range of a function requires searching over all possible inputs. Even if a function is computable, its range might not be: every c.e. set, like the halting problem, is such.

Comment: So this additional axiom is the culprit since it's the *only* additional axiom. (The way this additional axiom is usually phrased, though, is "For every set $X$, the [Turing jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump) of $X$ exists." While more technical, this is better fits the unifying computability-theoretic theme of the subject.) Note that ACA$_0$ **cannot** actually prove that the "maximal common part" of any two models of arithmetic exists; in some sense, it's "barely" able to prove that arithmetic has a standard model.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in the ACA$_0$ context we need to be more careful than usual about what we mean by "arithmetic" - PA would be an *inappropriate* choice here, since in fact ACA$_0$ *cannot* prove that PA has a model, let alone that PA is true of the "canonical" natural numbers! See the first part of [this Mathoverflow answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/a/343285/8133).